# getReference databinding for maps

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, javascript, reference

seems I have found a bug which prevents data binding in case of arrayed Maps. Maybe you can help me how to get around this. I have a list of Custom Objects, I iterate over. Each of the components, I pass the custom Object and a map:

```
{
"Id1": [{Name: "Id1: test"},{Name: "Id2: test2"}],
"Id2": [{Name: "test3"}]
}
```

The Name value is passed via a component.getReference to a subcomponent: component.getReference("v.map."+Id+"[0].Name").

When I change the value of Name in the subcomponent, this is not reflected in the rendering of the other subcomponent. javascript is totally aware of the changed value (i.e. I can check with a console.log), but if I draw the Name value on every component (via a hardbinded Id --> {!v.map.Id1[0].Name}) I can see, that it only updates within the specific subcomponent, but the parent and all other Childs of the parent are not updated automatically. In case of basic datatypes (e.g. a boolean value) all objects get updated accordingly with the specific value.

You can find the semi-automatic updated binding in both screenshots. "test" is the init value:
[image: rendering after init]
[image: rendering after changing the referenced value]

Is there a way around this? Can we enforce a render/data-binding update?
This might be a bit complicated, so please let me know if you need a concrete example.

Thanks,
Nico

Comment: A self-contained example would be useful, if you can write a small short one that we could use to get a better idea.

Comment: meanwhile, I have found the following known issue: https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p3A0000018B6LQAU. you can use the example there. The problem is, that a button is not really applicable in my case, because I want to automatically change it based on the input of a data field...